# How to route traffic from one interface to another regardless of source ip?

Tags: linux, networking, routing, iptables

I asked this question on network engineering, but they told me it was off-topic there and I should therefore try on superuser.

So, I'm deploying some raspberry pis for a specific network task.

I'm setting them up in the office, test the network task and then send them to the customer.

It all works fine with DHCP enabled.

However, there are some customers who would like to use a fixed IP for the raspberry in their intranet. Right now, I'm setting up the machine, test it, then change the ip address and then send it out - because I cannot check the network task after I changed the ip address. Our subnet ist 192.168.0.0\24 and the customers subnet can be pretty much anything, and I cannot get raspberrys with a different subnet to connect to the internet - which would be great for testing purposes.

My idea was to buy a second network interface for my (linux) workstation and connect the raspberry to it. Then the traffic from the raspberry would come to my workstation and I can route it to the internet.

But now I'm stuck. I can't get it to work, I tried some iptables stuff, but it isn't working. Can anybody help me on how to setup my interfaces/iptables to get it to work?

My setup:

eth0 is my primary network interface that has internet access

eth1 is my second network, where the raspberry will be connected to

our subnet: 192.168.0.0\24

clients subnet: anything

Thanks!

PS: regarding the comments on my original posting on network engineering: i have ipv4 forwarding enabled. I don't know how to implement a NAT, but i would of course find out, if that's the solution

Comment: Does your eth1 interface have an IP address? It must, or none of this will work. When it does, and you can ping the raspberry from your workstation and *viceversa*, then `iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -i eth1 -o eth0 -j MASQUERADE` will do the trick for you.

Comment: You write "I asked this question on network engineering, but they told me it was off-topic there "  <--- on that note, i'd note that you got your \ and / mixed up.   The CIDR notation is `192.168.0.0/24` a forward slash not a backslash.  Forward slash is the one where the top looks like it's falling forward like in the direction of the writing, head falling to the right. Like /?